# Deleted /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb by mistake

Tags: centos, centos6, sssd

I deleted **/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb** by mistake. Now when I try to start SSSD, I get the following errors:

```
(Wed Nov 23 11:40:36:059914 2016) [sssd] [check_file] (0x0400): lstat for [/var/run/nscd/socket] failed: [2][No such file or directory].
(Wed Nov 23 11:40:36:061661 2016) [sssd] [ldb] (0x0400): ltdb: tdb(/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb: No such file or directory

(Wed Nov 23 11:40:36:061686 2016) [sssd] [ldb] (0x0020): Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb': No such file or directory
(Wed Nov 23 11:40:36:061699 2016) [sssd] [ldb] (0x0020): Failed to connect to '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb' with backend 'tdb': Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb': No such file or directory
(Wed Nov 23 11:40:36:061709 2016) [sssd] [confdb_init] (0x0010): Unable to open config database [/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb]
(Wed Nov 23 11:40:36:061838 2016) [sssd] [load_configuration] (0x0010): The confdb initialization failed
(Wed Nov 23 11:40:36:061865 2016) [sssd] [main] (0x0020): SSSD couldn't load the configuration database.
```

How do I restore this file?

Comment: Some of the Google hits I am finding suggest that you should just  reinstall SSSD, and it will re-create the file.

Comment: @Zoredache, that didn't help :( completely removed sssd and re-installed it. same error.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest.  Maybe perform a completely new install of an identical version in a VM and then copy the file?

Comment: Thanks @Zoredache. That worked. I copied from a Ubuntu to a CentOS VM. Worked just fine! :) If you make this a answer, I will accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

Try `yum reinstall sssd-common`, this worked for me.

Comment: Please read comments to post, it was first suggestion and it not work.

Comment: sssd-common and sssd are two different packages.

Comment: my fault, sorry.

Comment: equivalent apt install sssd-common worked on our Ubuntu 20.04 system